# How can I plug in my own NER into the Stanford NLP parser pipeline?

Tags: parsing, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to provide parsing on some biodiversity literature but I have my own NER tool that I have developed to identify species names. I need to plug this into the parser pipeline somehow to enhance the dependency parsing but I am not sure how to go about it and haven't been able to find anything that gives me an indication how to approach it.

My tagger is just a simple dictionary look up that runs in Python 3.6.

Any ideas?